# Fix explicit link warning

Tags: doxygen

I have rather big project with doxygen and some files marked as @internal, some not.
When I build internal documentation no warnings are generated, but when I try to build not internal I got some warnings:

some_header.h:61 warning: explicit link request to 'MyStruct' could not be resolved
some_header.h:58 warning: explicit link request to 'AnotherMyStruct' could not be resolved
some_header.h:58 warning: explicit link request to 'AnotherMyStruct' could not be resolved
some_header.h:61 warning: explicit link request to 'MyStruct' could not be resolved

But some_header.h is internal. As an idea I think that it is included in non internal file, but it is wrong. I deleted all includes of the header, but the message doesn't gone.
How can I fix this warning?
P.S. duplicates of warning mean that there 2 places with error?

```
$doxygen -x
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
QUIET                  = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = NO
WARN_FORMAT            =
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c *.h
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       =
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = NO
HTML_OUTPUT            =
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           =
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
USE_PDFLATEX           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             =
MAN_LINKS              = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = (a lot of)
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
```

Simple example to reproduce problem:
flags.h:

```
/**
 * @file
 * @brief Public Flags.
 */
#ifndef PUBLIC_FLAGS_H
#define PUBLIC_FLAGS_H
#pragma once
    
/**
 * Public flags
 */
typedef enum {
    FLAG_READ           = 1,    /**< reading allowed         */
    FLAG_WRITE          = 2,   /**< writing allowed         */
} PublicFlags;

#endif /* PUBLIC_FLAGS_H */
```

info.h

```
/**
 * @file
 * @brief Public header.
*/
#ifndef TEST_PUBLIC_H
#define TEST_PUBLIC_H
#pragma once

#include "flags.h"

/**
 * Defines public enum.
 */
typedef enum EPublicEnum {
    TestEnum1,    /**< enum 1 */
    TestEnum2,    /**< enum 2 */
    TestEnum3     /**< enum 3 */
} PublicEnum;

/**
 * Defines public struct.
 */
typedef struct SPublicStruct {
    PublicEnum     state;    /**< state (see #PublicEnum). */
    unsigned      flags;     /**< set of flags see #PublicFlags.*/
} PublicStruct;

#endif /* TEST_PUBLIC_H */
```

internal_enums.h

```
/**
 * @internal
 * @file
 * @brief  Internal Enums
 */
#ifndef INTERNAL_ENUMS_H
#define INTERNAL_ENUMS_H
#pragma once

#include "flags.h"
#include "info.h"

/**
 * Possible types:
 *
 *  TypeMisc - Misc type.
 *  TypeIo   - IO type.
 */
typedef enum {
    TypeMisc,
    TypeIo,
} InternalEnumType;

/** Owner type. */
typedef enum {
    Kernel  = 0,    /**< kernel. */
    User    = 1     /**< user. */
} InternalEnumOwner;

#endif /* INTERNAL_ENUMS_H */
```

internal_struct.h

```
/**
 * @internal
 * @file
 * @brief  Internal structures.
 */
#ifndef INTERNAL_STRUCT_H
#define INTERNAL_STRUCT_H

#include "internal_enums.h"

typedef struct SInternalStruct {
    rtl_uint8_t   owner : 1;        /**< values from #InternalEnumOwner */
    rtl_uint8_t   type : 1;         /**< values from #InternalEnumType */
} InternalStruct;

#endif /* INTERNAL_STRUCT_H */
```

problem:
warning: explicit link request to 'InternalEnumOwner' could not be resolved

warning: explicit link request to 'InternalEnumType' could not be resolved

Comment: I try to make documentation only for the folder with some_header and also got this warning, so I think problem is in doxygen configuration, but I don,t have any ideas what option I need.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What is there in your doxygen configuration different from the default configuration (`doxygen -x Doxyfile`)? Please show minimal example, without it is not possible to give a sensible answer.

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.13
What is -x option? error: Unknown option "-x"
I use own DOXYFILE. Main options are:
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c *.h
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           =
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
and a lot of PREDEFINED             =

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.13 is a bit older (September 6, 2016), advise is to update to the current version (1.9.3). Also in doxygen 1.8.13 the `doxygen -x` doesn't work, as that feature is available since 1.8.15, so you have to see what the differences are between the Doxyfile you used and the default Doxyfile.

Comment: Additional fact: after generating documentation I open index.html->data structures->data structures and see all internal structures from the project. But index.html->files->file list shows all files, but internal is not a links. This is in both doxygen versions.

Comment: I've updated to Doxygen 1.9.4, but problem is still here.
Doxygen -x output:
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
QUIET                  = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = NO
WARN_FORMAT            =
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c *.h
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       =

Comment: SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = NO
HTML_OUTPUT            =
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           =
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
USE_PDFLATEX           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             =
MAN_LINKS              = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = (a lot of)
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES

Comment: I started doxygen with QUEIT = NO and find out that generating docs for internal files are skipped, but "generating docs for compound (SomeInternalStruct)" is still happens.

Comment: The setting is not `QUEIT` but `QUIET` but I think this is just a typo in the comment. Regarding the settings you placed in the comment, they should not be in a comment as they are an essential part of the issue, so please edit them into question.

Comment: Yes. just typo. Done

Comment: duplicates of warning mean that there 2 places with error? No doxygen just sees twice the same problem.

Comment: What are the differences between an "internal run" and a "non internal run" (just the setting of `INTERNAL_DOCS`) ? Please show minimal example, without it is not possible to give a sensible answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. What do you mean in minimal example? some short files that will reproduce warning?

Comment: Indeed, a short example so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've add 4 simple files to question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding about what the `\internal` command does in doxygen does, from the documentation:

> 24.29 \internal
>
> This command starts a documentation fragment that is meant for internal use only. The fragment naturally ends
> at the end of the comment block. You can also force the internal section to end earlier by using the \endinternal
> command.
> If the \internal command is put inside a section (see for example \section) all subsections after the command
> are considered to be internal as well. Only a new section at the same level will end the fragment that is considered
> internal.
> You can use INTERNAL_DOCS in the configuration file to show (YES) or hide (NO) the internal documentation.

This means that the comment between the `\internal` and the `\endinternal` (or end of the comment block) is not part of the documentation (unless the setting `INTERNAL_DOCS` is set), in this case it is just about the parts like:

```
/**
 * @internal
 * @file
 * @brief  Internal structures.
 */
```

so the `\internal` command here has not the desired effect and should be removed.

What actually is desired (when I understand it correctly) is that the entire file isn't used. This can be accomplished by means of either:

- add the setting `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = internal*`

or

- explicitly listing all files and directories that should be used, her this is by adding the setting `INPUT = info.h flags.h`

In case only part of a file, i.e documentation and code, should not enter the documentation one can use the commands `\cond ... \endcond`. For disabling just part of a documentation block the commands `\if ..  \endif` are useful. Both sets of commands go together with the setting `ENABLED_SECTIONS`.

For a description of the mentioned command see the doxygen manual (e.g. at https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html and more specifically the chapters: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html and https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html)